# How to Filter Rows by ID and then Update other Rows that have Same ID

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm new to writing SQL statements, so forgive me if this is a loopy way of asking an SQL question. This is pertaining to the wp_postmeta database of Wordpress, by the way.

I'm attempting to take the rows selected in this statement I wrote:

```
SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'pb-city'
```

And use these post_id's to filter in rows with the SAME post_id but a different key in the meta_key column. At that point, I believe the code I would run might look something like this:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value='locations-page' WHERE meta_key='_wp_page_template'
```

I believe the issue is that I don't know how to  filter my scope when updating the table. I know how to filter, and I know how to update, but I don't know how to take a filtered table and update certain values.

Any advice?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There a are a couple ways to do this.  Here's one joining the table back to itself assuming your unique identifier is named `id`:

```
update wp_postmeta p1
  join wp_postmeta p2 on p1.id <> p2.id and p1.post_id = p2.post_id
set p1.meta_value='locations-page' 
where p1.meta_key='_wp_page_template'
  and p2.meta_key = 'pb-city';
```

- [Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/303f0/1)

---

Alternatively, you could also use `EXISTS` with a correlated subquery, but you'll have to use an additional subquery as there is a slight limitation with your `rdbms` and updating records when using the same table in a subquery:

```
update wp_postmeta p1
set p1.meta_value='locations-page' 
where p1.meta_key='_wp_page_template' 
  and exists (
    select 1
    from (select * from wp_postmeta) p2
    where p1.id <> p2.id
      and p2.meta_key = 'pb-city'
      and p1.post_id = p2.post_id
    )
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b610a/1)

---

Edit:

Rereading your post, perhaps you don't have an `id` field but rather you just want to join on `meta_key` not being the same.  If that is the case, you can use just remove `p1.id <> p2.id` from the queries.

Answer (score 0):

try this for select

select * from wp_postmeta where post_id in (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'pb-city') and meta_key <> 'pb-city'

Update depends on your scope for example

update wp_postmeta  set SET meta_value='locations-page' WHERE  post_id in (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'pb-city') and meta_key = '_wp_page_template'

Before update try the result with

select * from wp_postmeta  WHERE  post_id in (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'pb-city') and meta_key = '_wp_page_template'

Comment: select * from wp_postmeta where post_id in (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'pb-city') ----- this seems to work well to retrieve the values I'm looking for, but how would I update this filtered table?